# how to create a java class file from context of a String

Tags: java, dynamic, compilation

I want to achieve providing a string like = "System.out.println(1)",while running program to dynamicly create a class having this codes as a function.

i have tried org.apache.commons.jexl2 package,but it seems to me a beginner it only work on a single expression

```
public static Object invokeMethod(String jexlExp, Map<String,Object> map){
    JexlEngine jexl=new JexlEngine();
    Expression e = jexl.createExpression(jexlExp);
    JexlContext jc = new MapContext();
    for(String key:map.keySet()){
        jc.set(key, map.get(key));
    }
    if(null==e.evaluate(jc)){
        return "";
    }
    return e.evaluate(jc);
}
public static void main(String[]args){
    Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String,Object>();
    map.put("money",3000);
    String expression="{if(money==3000)return 30000}";
    Object code = invokeMethod(expression,map);
    out.println(code);

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to achieve that? Dynamic code generation is suitable for only specific tasks, and you may be trying to use the wrong tool in this case.

Comment: it is like a game?  i want the users to input their code to run on this application, it is far beyond my ability

Comment: You can use the Nashorn JavaScript interpreter which is included in the JRE. Users can enter JavaScript and it can fairly transparently interface with Java classes (both JRE and your own)

Answer (score 0):

You might wan to give jexl3 a try; it does not 'create a class' or generate byte-code but it will interpret scripts.